# Breezejs Byte Property Validation Error

Tags: validation, knockout.js, byte, breeze

I'm trying to create a small application using breezejs, knockout and webapi. However I have encountered an issue, possibly a bug when using a Byte data type for a property.

I manage to pass the data correctly and bind it to the textbox, however when i try to update it, an error will appear stating that the "Priority must be an integer between the values 0 and 255"

I have a small sample to demonstrate this issue:

**Getting Started:**
I've downloaded http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download the samples (currently 1.2.8)

Opened the ToDo Sample

In TodoItem.cs added another property, in my case i added Priority of type **(byte)**

```
public byte Priority { get; set; }
```

Added some data seeding in TodoDatabaseInitializer.cs

```
    public static void SeedDatabase(TodosContext context)
    {
        _baseCreatedAtDate = new DateTime(2012, 8, 22, 9, 0, 0);

        var todos = new[] {
            // Description, IsDone, IsArchived
            CreateTodo("Food", true, true, 1),
            CreateTodo("Water", true, true, 2),
            CreateTodo("Shelter", true, true, 10),
            CreateTodo("Bread", false, false, 20),
            CreateTodo("Cheese", true, false, 20),
            CreateTodo("Wine", false, false, 3)
       };

        Array.ForEach(todos, t => context.Todos.Add(t));

        context.SaveChanges(); // Save 'em
    }

    private static TodoItem CreateTodo(
        string description, bool isDone, bool isArchived, byte priority)
    {
        _baseCreatedAtDate = _baseCreatedAtDate.AddMinutes(1);
        return new TodoItem
        {
            CreatedAt = _baseCreatedAtDate,
            Description = description,
            IsDone = isDone,
            IsArchived = isArchived,
            Priority = priority
        };
    }
```

And finally added a textbox in the UI in Index.html, by adding the following line in the items data-bind:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Priority" />
```

It would look like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <div data-bind="visible: !isEditing()">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Priority" />
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsDone" />
            <label data-bind="text: Description, click: $parent.edit, css: { done: IsDone, archived: IsArchived }"></label>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: isEditing">
            <form data-bind="event: { submit: $parent.completeEdit }">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description, hasfocus: isEditing" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

After doing so, run the app and if you try to modify an entry an error will appear stating that the "Priority must be an integer between the values 0 and 255"

Also I want to mention that if i change the type of the priority to int, it works fine.

Is it actually a bug or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This was fixed in Breeze v1.3.0, available now.

---

Ok, this is a bug and will be fixed in the next version, probably released next week. I will post back here when it gets released.  ... and thanks for finding this :)